# Binding an object sent via jquery post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I am making an method on my site via JavaScript.

```
var Type1= { Var: "Test" };
var Type2= { Var2: "Test2" };

var Combo= {Type1: Type1}, Type2: Type2;

$.post("http://mysite/contoller/save", Combo, function (data) {
        someOtherFunction(data);
});
```

The method I hit on the other side takes a type Combo. When My method is hit the content of Type1 and Type 2 in Combo are null.

When I make the method take Type1 instead of Combo and only pass Type1 into the post the content is not null. Can you not send through complex types?

Comment: What does your complex type look like in the save action?

Comment: It will Have Type1, Type but Var and Var2 will be null.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , Use $.ajax() with type - POST. $.post() is deprecated.

Use Json to send your object. Use a plugin Json.js. Convert your object as:

var jsonObject = $.toJSON(ComboObject);

Now pass this as a parameter of this 'post' request. Retrieve from Controller.

Any doubts?